# Чтение файла! как каждую строку присвоить к переменной?

Tags: php

читаем файл `file();`

---

```
function red_file(){
    $red = file('1.txt');
    $massiv = array();
    foreach ($massiv as $line_num=>$line){
    $massiv[]=explode('',trim($line));
}
return massiv;
}
```

---

при всем уважение к массивам, не могу понять почему это не работает?!? хочу взять каждую строку файла как отдельную переменную! не получается, или выводиться array или ничего не выводится! в чем проблема? может есть какое-то другое решение данной задачи?
пытался читать файл как `fgets()`, но там выводится как одна строка, которую тяжело порезать `explode()`...

Comment: @tagir, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Вы пустой массив $massiv прогоняете через foreach и хотите какой-то результат? )) А возвращаете что - return massiv;?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Код не проверял, но должно работать

```
<?php

function readFile($filename) {
    $data = array();
    $file = fopen($filename, 'r');
    if (!$file) return false;

    while (!feof($file)) { // пока файл не кончился, продолжаем цикл
        $line = fgets($file, 9999);
        $data[] = $line;
    }

    return $data; // вывести массив    
}

?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare readFile()

Comment: на самом-то деле оказалось все очень просто!
<?
  $file_array = file("file.txt");
  if(!$file_array)
  {
    echo("Ошибка открытия файла");
  }
  else
  {
    for($i=0; $i < count($file_array); $i++)
    {
      printf("%s<br>", $file_array[$i]);
    }
  }
?>

Comment: ну вот, количество голосов -2, сейчас не могу даже поставить правильный ответ!(((

Comment: `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare readFile()` - это значит вы два и более раз пытаетесь обозначить функцию с одним и тем же именем просто поменяйте имя функции.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).